# Classify data using Apache Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following *ds*:

```
|-- created_at: timestamp (nullable = true)
|-- channel_source_id: integer (nullable = true)
|-- movie_id: integer (nullable = true)
```

I would like to classify the *movie_id* based on some conditions:

- Number of times have been played;

  ```
  #Count ocurrences by ID
  SELECT COUNT(createad_at) FROM logs GROUP BY movie_id
  ```
- What is the range (*created_at*) that movie has been played;

  ```
  #Returns distinct movies_id
  SELECT DISTINCT(movie_id) FROM logs

  #For each movie_id, I would like to retrieve the hour that has been played
  #When i have the result, I could apply an filter from df to extract the intervals
  SELECT created_at FROM logs WHERE movie_id = ?
  ```
- Number of differents *channel_source_id* that have played the movie;

  ```
  #Count number of channels that have played
  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(channel_source_id)) FROM logs where movie_id = ? GROUP BY movie_id
  ```

I've written a simple table to help me on classification

```
Played 1 to 5 times, range between 00:00:00 - 03:59:59, 1 to 3 different channels >> Movie Type A
Played 6 to 10 times, range between 04:00:00 - 07:59:59, 4 to 5 different channels >> Movie Type B
etc
```

I'm using Spark to import file but i'm lost how can I perform the classification. Anyone could me give me a hand on where should I start?

```
def run() = {
  val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
  val df = sqlContext.read
    .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
    .options(Map("header" -> "true", "inferSchema" -> "true"))
    .load("/home/plc/Desktop/movies.csv")
  df.printSchema()
}
```

Comment: "Anyone could me give me a hand on where should i start?" What are you looking for, other than (it might seem) someone to write the code for you? What (plain SQL) queries might give you the results you want? Prepare those and then look at how those could be done with a dataframe?

Comment: I don't need anyone writing my code, buddy. I'm really lost using spark and any help could be great. This is my first time using a map/reduce framework.

Comment: OK, so... what queries do you think would give you the results you need? I assume this is an assignment or at least some example problem as it's structured to ask you to do three different things (count the occurrences, merge things into a min/max pair,  find the distinct values)

Comment: Your problem is with the concept of Map Reduce? Do you have experience with SQL?

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul check the update. I've put that queries that i was thinking to solve that 3 problems

Comment: "SELECT COUNT(createad_at) FROM logs GROUP BY movie_id  ". So now look for groupBy, in the dataframe API,,,look at the examples there, and also http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.RelationalGroupedDataset